# Problem with checkbox and database in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I tried to save the checkbox through "INSERT INTO", but after the .get () method is triggered, zero is constantly written to the database, how I can solve this problem?

When starting the program, it writes two zeros to the variable, although if the checkbox is active, one must be written.

Code:

```
var1 = IntVar()

c1 = Checkbutton(text="First", variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)

c1.pack(anchor=W)

var2 = IntVar()

c2 = Checkbutton(text="Second", variable=var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)

c2.pack(anchor=W)


conn = sqlite3.connect("MyDB.db")

cursor = conn.cursor()

conn.execute("INSERT INTO TestDB VALUES (:var1, :var2)", {'var1': var1.get(), 'var2': var2.get()})

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

No console errors. Values into DB(zero, in any case, it doesn’t matter if the checkbox is active or not) - https://ibb.co/B6jBDTV

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] instead of linking to code on another site.

Comment: You are getting the value about a millisecond after creating the checkbutton, far before the user even sees the UI.

Comment: I should use time.sleep() method or smth like that?

Comment: No. You need to work through a tkinter tutorial so that you understand the basic concepts of event-driven programming. Here's one place to start: https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a function that will get variable of checkbox and function that write this variable into my DB, this is code:

```py
root = Tk()
root.title("getcheck")
root.geometry("350x250")

def create_DB():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("MyDB.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestDB (var1 integer, var2 integer)""")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def get_var():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("MyDB.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO TestDB VALUES (:var1, :var2)", {'var1': var1.get(), 'var2': var2.get()})
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()



btn = Button(root, text = "create_db", command = create_DB).pack(anchor = W)
btn1 = Button(root, text = "get value", command = get_var).pack(anchor = W)


var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text = "first var", variable = var1).place(x = 75,y = 1)

var2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text = "second var", variable = var2).place(x = 120, y = 28)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: And correct values from checkboxes write into my SQLite DB :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a decent initialization.

For this, you can initialize the value for `Checkbutton` by `ChkVar = []`

And then consider setting :

```
for i in range(0,2):
    ChkVar.append(0)

ChkVar[0] = IntVar(value=ChkVar[0])
ChkVar[1] = IntVar(value=ChkVar[1])
```

If you want your Checkbutton item should be unchecked at the beginning, use

`Checkbutton(text="First", variable=ChkVar[0])`,

otherwise `Checkbutton(text="Second", variable=ChkVar[1])`

Note that, we removed `, onvalue=1, offvalue=0` part in this method.

And lastly ( assuming your Checkbuttons is unchecked at the beginning ), 
Rearrange your `INSERT` Statement as

`conn.execute("INSERT INTO TestDB VALUES (:var1, :var2)", {'var1': ChkVar[0].get(), 'var2': ChkVar[1].get()})`

***Sample code depending on above Caveats***:

```
from tkinter import *

wnd = Tk()

ChkVar = []

def printCb():
    print(ChkVar[0].get())
    print(ChkVar[1].get())    

wnd.geometry('370x130')

renk_z="green"

wnd.resizable(width=False,height=False)

wnd.configure(background=renk_z)

for i in range(0,2):
    ChkVar.append(0)

ChkVar.append(1)
ChkVar[0] = IntVar(value=ChkVar[0])
ChkVar[1] = IntVar(value=ChkVar[1])
Checkbutton(wnd, text="First",bg=renk_z,variable=ChkVar[0]).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
Checkbutton(wnd, text="Second",bg=renk_z,variable=ChkVar[1]).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)

Button(wnd,text="Print",width=5,command=printCb,bg=renk_z).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)

#conn.execute("INSERT INTO TestDB VALUES (:var1, :var2)", {'var1': ChkVar[0].get(), 'var2': ChkVar[1].get()})

wnd.mainloop()
```

As you check/uncheck Check buttons and then press `Print` button you'll see the value of them are as printed. You can use those values by activating commented part which is related to interaction with the database.

Comment: If I follow your proposed option, there will be an error "List index out of range"

Comment: @DmitryGritsov I think I didn't add `ChkVar.append(1)` at the beginning of ChkVar[] settings.

Comment: Anyway, the same error at this string "ChkVar[1] = IntVar(value=ChkVar[1])"

Comment: It works, but zero still write into DB. I need to follow Bryan's Oakley suggest and read the tutorial

Comment: @DmitryGritsov Oh, my bad, I should write `ChkVar[1].get()` for `var2` within your `INSERT` statement. Can you try for last time.

Comment: I think it's not about initialization, zeros write into DB as soon as I start my program.